# Proving $\int ^{2\pi} _{0} (\cos(t)^{2n})={2n \choose {n}}\frac{2\pi}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: trigonometry, binomial-theorem, cauchy-integral-formula

using the following result

$\int _{\gamma}(z+ \frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{dz}{z}= {2n \choose {n}}2\pi i $

Prove

$\int ^{2\pi} _{0} (\cos(t)^{2n})={2n \choose {n}}\frac{2\pi}{2^{2n}}$

I cant see how the second part can be put in this form is there any suggestions? Also used Cauchy integral formula and binomial expansion to prove first part.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\gamma=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Then $\int_\gamma (z+1/z)^{2n}(1/z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos t)^{2n}(\cos t-i\sin t)(-\sin t+i\cos t)dt=i\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos t)^{2n}dt={2n\choose n}2\pi i.$

And the rest follows.

Comment: It's line integral, we are integrating over a curve where we have a parametric form of the curve $\gamma=\{\cos t+i\sin t : 0\leq t<2\pi\}.$

Comment: @John_Wick, what's the meaning of $\gamma={(x,y)|(x^2+y^2=1)}$

Comment: I meant unit circle on complex plane centered at zero.

Comment: https://services.math.duke.edu/education/ccp/materials/engin/cint1/cint1.html check here how to calculate line integral on the complex plane.