# Prove that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Prove that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$

**My attempt:**

I know by the cauchy form:

$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366304/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481356/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3011547/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D(2%5Ccos%5Ctheta)%5E%7B2n%7Dd%5Ctheta%3D%5Cfrac%7B2n!%7D%7Bn!n!%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: If you want to do it by complex analysis note that the integrand is $(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{dz}{z}$ up to some $i$ and the residue at $0$ is precisely the middle coefficient of the binomial (in other words the constant term because of the $\frac{dz}{z}$ which unsurprisingly is the answer!

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx,~ if ~ f(2a-x)=f(x).$$
$$I=\frac{2^{2n}}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}t dt=4\frac{2^{2n}}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n}t dt=\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n} t dt=\frac{2^{2n}}{\pi} \frac{\Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!}.$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}.$$
Here we have used the beta integral: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^p x \cos^q x dx=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma((p+1)/2)\Gamma((q+1)/2)}{\Gamma((p+q+2)/2)}$$